# How to add a large number of videos to your app without significantly increasing its size with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

So i'm working on an app in android studio that involves uploading large amounts of data and specifically videos to the app. And by large i mean thousands of short 30 seconds videos where each video wouldn't be more than 5-10MB, but right away i faced the problem of increasing my simple app's size which would ruin it completely. I would appreciate any ideas that would help me accomplish such an idea.

I have not tried anything to help solve the problem

Comment: What do you consider to be 'uploading' in this respect?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, i don't mean uploading in the same way you upload a video from your gallery to youtube inside the app, NO. I mean an offline app that has videos inside of it ready to be watched

Comment: You're has a limited size; and that should be for best user experience; imagine that some users don't like to see certain type of videos; why they are forced to download them? .. Putting them onto the cloud is the alternative for that.

Comment: you can upload the video to some server and let the user download videos they like. you can split videos into some categories or so